# CTE Code just grabbing anchor not making recursion

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, recursion, ssms, common-table-expression

query is not making the recursion, it only fetches the anchor part (the ids where parent id is null).

Can anyone help me spot my mistake? I have tried a lot things but I am always retrieving the same number of rows, the IDS with no parent ids.

```
WITH EmpTree
AS (
    SELECT e.DWH_Dim_TFS_File_DWH_FileParent_Guid
        ,e.DWH_Dim_TFS_File_DWH_File_Guid
        ,1 AS Depth
        ,File_Name_String = CAST(CAST(e.File_Name AS BINARY (100)) AS VARBINARY(8000))
    FROM [dbo].[Hierarchy_Luis] AS e
    WHERE e.DWH_Dim_TFS_File_DWH_FileParent_Guid IS NULL

    UNION ALL

    SELECT e.DWH_Dim_TFS_File_DWH_FileParent_Guid
        ,e.DWH_Dim_TFS_File_DWH_File_Guid
        ,p.Depth + 1 AS Depth
        ,File_Name_String = CAST(CONCAT (
                p.File_Name_String
                ,CAST(e.File_Name AS BINARY (100))
                ) AS VARBINARY(8000))
    FROM [dbo].[Hierarchy_Luis] AS e
    JOIN EmpTree AS p ON e.DWH_Dim_TFS_File_DWH_FileParent_Guid = p.DWH_Dim_TFS_File_DWH_File_Guid
    )
SELECT p.DWH_Dim_TFS_File_DWH_File_Guid
    ,p.Depth
    ,Level01 = CAST(SUBSTRING(p.File_Name_String, 1, 100) AS NVARCHAR(100))
    ,Level02 = CAST(SUBSTRING(p.File_Name_String, 101, 100) AS NVARCHAR(100))
    ,Level03 = CAST(SUBSTRING(p.File_Name_String, 201, 100) AS NVARCHAR(100))
    ,Level04 = CAST(SUBSTRING(p.File_Name_String, 301, 100) AS NVARCHAR(100))
    ,Level05 = CAST(SUBSTRING(p.File_Name_String, 401, 100) AS NVARCHAR(100))
    ,Level07 = CAST(SUBSTRING(p.File_Name_String, 501, 100) AS NVARCHAR(100))
    ,Level08 = CAST(SUBSTRING(p.File_Name_String, 601, 100) AS NVARCHAR(100))
    ,Level09 = CAST(SUBSTRING(p.File_Name_String, 701, 100) AS NVARCHAR(100))
    ,Level10 = CAST(SUBSTRING(p.File_Name_String, 801, 100) AS NVARCHAR(100))
    ,Level11 = CAST(SUBSTRING(p.File_Name_String, 901, 100) AS NVARCHAR(100))
    ,Level12 = CAST(SUBSTRING(p.File_Name_String, 1001, 100) AS NVARCHAR(100))
    ,Level13 = CAST(SUBSTRING(p.File_Name_String, 1101, 100) AS NVARCHAR(100))
    ,Level14 = CAST(SUBSTRING(p.File_Name_String, 1201, 100) AS NVARCHAR(100))
    ,Level15 = CAST(SUBSTRING(p.File_Name_String, 1301, 100) AS NVARCHAR(100))
    ,Level16 = CAST(SUBSTRING(p.File_Name_String, 1401, 100) AS NVARCHAR(100))
    ,Level17 = CAST(SUBSTRING(p.File_Name_String, 1501, 100) AS NVARCHAR(100))
    ,Level18 = CAST(SUBSTRING(p.File_Name_String, 1601, 100) AS NVARCHAR(100))
    ,Level19 = CAST(SUBSTRING(p.File_Name_String, 1701, 100) AS NVARCHAR(100))
    ,Level20 = CAST(SUBSTRING(p.File_Name_String, 1801, 100) AS NVARCHAR(100))
    ,Level21 = CAST(SUBSTRING(p.File_Name_String, 1901, 100) AS NVARCHAR(100))
    ,Level22 = CAST(SUBSTRING(p.File_Name_String, 2001, 100) AS NVARCHAR(100))
    ,Level23 = CAST(SUBSTRING(p.File_Name_String, 2101, 100) AS NVARCHAR(100))
    ,Level24 = CAST(SUBSTRING(p.File_Name_String, 2201, 100) AS NVARCHAR(100))
    ,Level25 = CAST(SUBSTRING(p.File_Name_String, 2301, 100) AS NVARCHAR(100))
    ,Level26 = CAST(SUBSTRING(p.File_Name_String, 2401, 100) AS NVARCHAR(100))
    ,Level27 = CAST(SUBSTRING(p.File_Name_String, 2501, 100) AS NVARCHAR(100))
FROM EmpTree p
```

[You can see in the link the two columns data types where the recursion is being made, it is a nvarchar(256)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5puep.png)

Thanks a lot, I know it must be something quite basic, but I can not find out.

**Sample DATA**

```
DWH_Dim_TFS_File_DWH_FileParent_GUID    DWH_Dim_TFS_File_DWH_File_GUID  File_Name
114087616   114087617   ot_de
114087616   114087618   ot_de
114087593   114087619   _proj
11407441    11408762    I_EXP
114087593   114087620   arm\
114087620   114087621   e\
114087621   114087622   ot_de
114087621   114087623   ot_de
114087593   114087624   c\
114087624   114087625   ot_de
114087624   114087626   ot_de
114087593   114087627   3s896
114087593   114087628   kefil
114087593   114087629   adme.
11408762    11408763    B_PTS
114087593   114087630   mdk\
114087630   114087631   ot_de
114087630   114087632   ot_de
114087593   114087633   urcer
114087633   114087634   ot_de
114087633   114087635   ot_de
114087593   114087636   artup
114087593   114087637   artup
114087593   114087638   artup
114087593   114087639   artup
11408763    11408764    B_PTS
114087593   114087640   artup
114087302   114087641   ot_et
114087641   114087642   _conf
114087641   114087643   ot_et
114087641   114087644   ot_et
114087641   114087645   ot_et
114087641   114087646   ot_et
114087641   114087647   ot_et
114087641   114087648   s\
114087648   114087649   csimp
11408763    11408765    B_PTS
114087648   114087650   cspro
114087648   114087651   dtbui
114087648   114087652   dtpro
114087648   114087653   rojec
114087648   114087654   ettin
114087654   114087655   g.ecl
114087648   114087656   cros.
114087648   114087657   rget_
114087641   114087658   dered
114087658   114087659   ot_et
11408763    11408766    cessW
```

Comment: can you share some test data as dml

Comment: Look out this link (https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to know more on how to improve the queston

Comment: Ups, sorry guys, since my problem is merely the select and joins not working I thought no data would be necessary. The core of this problem is just on file_guid and fileparent_guid. I will give info about the data type

Comment: For better overview, please name your alias different in each select, otherwise you will get confused.

Comment: I did plaidDK, I changed Alias as well, but yeah I should have leave each one of the different, but it is not the issue here

Comment: Can you provide some sample data?

Comment: And are you sure, that you have any Guid that matches file_parent_guid where they are null?

Comment: I gave some sample data.
I checked if I had matching parents and guids and I did, but know that you mention I assumed the ones with null parents would have a match.. did not do that test :x gonna check it out

Comment: Ok thanks plaid, found my stupid mistake.
The top level have their parent id = "own id" and not null

Thanks again!

Comment: Please provide sample data as dml,it helps others and you as well

Comment: Plaid. Copy my code and put  FROM [dbo].[Hierarchy_Luis] AS e
    WHERE e.DWH_Dim_TFS_File_DWH_FileParent_Guid IS NULL to 

 FROM [dbo].[Hierarchy_Luis] AS e
    WHERE e.DWH_Dim_TFS_File_DWH_FileParent_Guid = e.DWH_Dim_TFS_File_DWH_File_Guid

so I can put your answer as correct, if you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer based on comments earlier:

The solution was that he did not have any match where they were null - He had to match them in first select.

```
WITH EmpTree
AS (
SELECT e.DWH_Dim_TFS_File_DWH_FileParent_Guid
    ,e.DWH_Dim_TFS_File_DWH_File_Guid
    ,1 AS Depth
    ,File_Name_String = CAST(CAST(e.File_Name AS BINARY (100)) AS VARBINARY(8000))

FROM [dbo].[Hierarchy_Luis] AS e WHERE e.DWH_Dim_TFS_File_DWH_FileParent_Guid = e.DWH_Dim_TFS_File_DWH_File_Guid

UNION ALL

SELECT e.DWH_Dim_TFS_File_DWH_FileParent_Guid
    ,e.DWH_Dim_TFS_File_DWH_File_Guid
    ,p.Depth + 1 AS Depth
    ,File_Name_String = CAST(CONCAT (
            p.File_Name_String
            ,CAST(e.File_Name AS BINARY (100))
            ) AS VARBINARY(8000))
FROM [dbo].[Hierarchy_Luis] AS e
JOIN EmpTree AS p ON e.DWH_Dim_TFS_File_DWH_FileParent_Guid = p.DWH_Dim_TFS_File_DWH_File_Guid
)
SELECT p.DWH_Dim_TFS_File_DWH_File_Guid
,p.Depth
,Level01 = CAST(SUBSTRING(p.File_Name_String, 1, 100) AS NVARCHAR(100))
,Level02 = CAST(SUBSTRING(p.File_Name_String, 101, 100) AS NVARCHAR(100))
,Level03 = CAST(SUBSTRING(p.File_Name_String, 201, 100) AS NVARCHAR(100))
,Level04 = CAST(SUBSTRING(p.File_Name_String, 301, 100) AS NVARCHAR(100))
,Level05 = CAST(SUBSTRING(p.File_Name_String, 401, 100) AS NVARCHAR(100))
,Level07 = CAST(SUBSTRING(p.File_Name_String, 501, 100) AS NVARCHAR(100))
,Level08 = CAST(SUBSTRING(p.File_Name_String, 601, 100) AS NVARCHAR(100))
,Level09 = CAST(SUBSTRING(p.File_Name_String, 701, 100) AS NVARCHAR(100))
,Level10 = CAST(SUBSTRING(p.File_Name_String, 801, 100) AS NVARCHAR(100))
,Level11 = CAST(SUBSTRING(p.File_Name_String, 901, 100) AS NVARCHAR(100))
,Level12 = CAST(SUBSTRING(p.File_Name_String, 1001, 100) AS NVARCHAR(100))
,Level13 = CAST(SUBSTRING(p.File_Name_String, 1101, 100) AS NVARCHAR(100))
,Level14 = CAST(SUBSTRING(p.File_Name_String, 1201, 100) AS NVARCHAR(100))
,Level15 = CAST(SUBSTRING(p.File_Name_String, 1301, 100) AS NVARCHAR(100))
,Level16 = CAST(SUBSTRING(p.File_Name_String, 1401, 100) AS NVARCHAR(100))
,Level17 = CAST(SUBSTRING(p.File_Name_String, 1501, 100) AS NVARCHAR(100))
,Level18 = CAST(SUBSTRING(p.File_Name_String, 1601, 100) AS NVARCHAR(100))
,Level19 = CAST(SUBSTRING(p.File_Name_String, 1701, 100) AS NVARCHAR(100))
,Level20 = CAST(SUBSTRING(p.File_Name_String, 1801, 100) AS NVARCHAR(100))
,Level21 = CAST(SUBSTRING(p.File_Name_String, 1901, 100) AS NVARCHAR(100))
,Level22 = CAST(SUBSTRING(p.File_Name_String, 2001, 100) AS NVARCHAR(100))
,Level23 = CAST(SUBSTRING(p.File_Name_String, 2101, 100) AS NVARCHAR(100))
,Level24 = CAST(SUBSTRING(p.File_Name_String, 2201, 100) AS NVARCHAR(100))
,Level25 = CAST(SUBSTRING(p.File_Name_String, 2301, 100) AS NVARCHAR(100))
,Level26 = CAST(SUBSTRING(p.File_Name_String, 2401, 100) AS NVARCHAR(100))
,Level27 = CAST(SUBSTRING(p.File_Name_String, 2501, 100) AS NVARCHAR(100))
FROM EmpTree p
```